# Evolution wraps links

Tags: evolution

I am sending document links with a very long path, and Evolution mail client is putting a line break in the middle of the URL. This breaks the link, and the receiver of the e-mail can't click on the link to load the document.

How can I disable line break/wrapping of links?

(I cannot switch to other e-mail clients because I need the Exchange plug in.)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using HTML formatted text, [you can insert a link by a right click of your mouse or by clicking 'Insert' -> 'Link...' or by clicking the according icon in the bar](https://help.gnome.org/users/evolution/stable/mail-composer-html-link.html.en).

If you are using plain text messages, you have to turn the line from "normal" text style to "Preformatted" text style to keep the editor from wrapping the lines.